# Uniform convergence of $\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\,\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Does
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
converge uniformly to $1/x$ on the set $A=(0,\infty)$? Our definition of uniform convergence is the following.

**Definition.** Let $A\subseteq\mathbf R$. Given $f(x,t)$ defined on $A\times[c,\infty)\subseteq \mathbf R^2$, assume $F(x) = \int_c^\infty f(x,t)\,\mathrm dt$ exists for all $x\in A$. We say the improper integral *converges uniformly* to $F(x)$ on $A$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M>c$ such that
$$
\bigg|F(x)-\int_c^df(x,t)\,\mathrm dt\bigg|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $d\ge M$ and all $x\in A$.

**What I have tried:** We have that $F(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\,\mathrm dt = 1/x$. If $f(x,t) = e^{-xt}$, then
$$
\bigg|F(x)-\int_0^df(x,t)\,\mathrm dt\bigg| = \frac{1}{xe^{xd}}.
$$
If $x$ is confined to some subinterval such as $[1/2,\infty)$ then the convergence is uniform since
$$
\frac{1}{xe^{xd}} \le \frac{2}{e^{d/2}},
$$
which can be made as small as we'd like, independently of $x\in [1/2,\infty)$ for sufficiently large $d$. Part of my confusion stems from not knowing how to properly negate the definition of uniform convergence. I would phrase the definition in terms of quantifiers as
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0,\:\exists M>0 \:\text{such that}\: d\ge M\:\text{and}\: x\in A\implies \bigg|F(x)-\int_c^df(x,t)\,\mathrm dt\bigg|<\varepsilon,
$$
so that its negation would be
$$
\exists\varepsilon>0,\:\forall M>0, \:d\ge M\:\text{and}\: x\in A\:\text{but}\:\bigg|F(x)-\int_c^df(x,t)\,\mathrm dt\bigg|\ge\varepsilon.
$$
So, it seems that since $x\in(0,\infty)$ can take on arbitrarily small values, $1/xe^{xd}$ can take on arbitrarily large values, and the convergence is not uniform, but it is hard to evaluate since we can also make $d$ arbitrarily large, if I am not mistaken about the negation of our definition. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nice problem :-) (+1) upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of uniform convergence is stated as follows.

> **The convergence of $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^\infty f(x,t)\,dt$ fails to be uniform if there exists a number $\displaystyle  \epsilon>0$, such that corresponding to an arbitrary number $\displaystyle  M\in (0,\infty)$, there exists a number $\displaystyle  d\in [M,\infty)$ and a number $\displaystyle  x\in A$ such that**
>
> **$$\left|\int_d^\infty f(x,t)\,dt\right|\ge \epsilon$$**

---

Here, we have $f(x,t)=e^{-xt}$ so that

$$\left|\int_d^\infty f(x,t)\,dt\right|=\frac{e^{-dx}}{x}$$

We take $\epsilon=e^{-1}$, $d\ge \max(1,M)$ and $x=1/d$.  Then, no matter how large $M$ is, we have

$$\frac{e^{-dx}}{x}=de^{-1}\ge e^{-1}=\epsilon$$

And we are done!

Comment: I switched the roles of $M$ and $d$ to be consistent with my definition as I posted it.

Comment: Question: if the integral converges uniformly on $[\epsilon,\infty)$ for all $\epsilon>0$, does that mean that the integral converges uniformly on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @AOrtiz No.  It does not imply that the integral uniformly converges on the open interval.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the right hand side of this for different values of c and d:

$\left|F\left(x\right)-\int_{c}^{d}e^{-xt}dt\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{c}e^{-xt}dt+\int_{d}^{\infty}e^{-xt}dt\right|$

The c term clearly converges uniformly (the integrand is uniformly bounded in t on [0,c] for all x>0). The question is, does the same hold for the d term (the tail)?

Comment: What about the fact that $d$ can be made arbitrarily large? My confusion is that it looks like no matter how big we take $n$ in $1/n$, say, we can just make $d$ even bigger. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Would you mind amending your answer?

Comment: The difficulty you were having is due to the fact that the value of the function is unbounded whenever you allow x to get arbitrarily close to 0. A common trick is to break up the domain of integration into one or more pieces—in this case, a small interval where the function doesn't get too big, and a large interval where the function gets arbitrarily small—an then to analyze the behavior on each to obtain the desired upper or lower bound. If the tail converges uniformly, then the whole thing converges uniformly; if the tail diverges, then the whole thing diverges.